# Automatic scroll to div using #div in url not working with url variable

Tags: url, html, variables, autoscroll

I am trying to auto-scroll to div using:

```
/index.php#tabletabs2?contact_added=1
```

when I use:

```
/index.php#tabletabs2
```

it works. How can I have both a variable and the auto-scroll working in my URL???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query part of the URL needs to be before the `#`. Browsers only send the part before the `#` to the server. The part after is for auto-scrolling to elements via their `id` or `name` attribute, e.g.

```
/index.php?contact_added=1#tabletabs2
```

See also the "[Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)" section of Wikipedia's "Universal Resource Locator" article.  Especially the description of [fragment identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#cite_ref-14).

Answer (score 0):

You have to have them in the correct order; ? goes before #:

```
/index.php?contact_added=1#tabletabs2
```